# How to make selected pins on top which are overlapped in the MapView in Java, in Android phone

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I got a problem in Android application, I don't know how to make the selected pins on top of overlaaped pins.

In objective-c, iPhone we use the below methods But, I don't know how it can be implemented in Android phone, java.

```
[annotationView.superview bringSubviewToFront:annotationView];
[annotationView.superview sendSubviewToBack:annotationView];
```

Please suggest any solution,

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a statelist drawable.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: I got by placing mapview.bringToFront()